# Comparing XML to live data variables in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I want to compare data that is stores in a XML-file to data i've just saved to variables in this command session. Is it even possible?

I read this article: http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2009/01/09/tipps-amp-tricks-using-compare-object.aspx

"Compare-Object is a great way of comparing result sets. You just need to be careful to make sure:

```
you are comparing the same object types (do not mix imported xml data with live data)
the syncWindow is large enough to cover the number of expected differences
you specify the properties you really want to compare
```

"

Please please tell me it is possible to compare imported xml data with live data :P

This is my XML:

```
<computer version="1.0">
  <hardware>
    <serialnr>78456214Q</serialnr>
    <systeminfo>
      <name>Macgyver</name>
      <domain>Inventory.Domain</domain>
      <manufacturer>TOSHIBA</manufacturer>
      <model>Satellite A300</model>
      <bitversion>x64-based PC</bitversion>
    </systeminfo>
    <gpu>
      <name>ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series</name>
      <status>OK</status>
    </gpu>
    <cpu>
      <name>Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5750  @ 2.00GHz</name>
      <manufacturer>GenuineIntel</manufacturer>
      <id>cpuid</id>
      <numberofcores>2</numberofcores>
      <addresswidth>64</addresswidth>
    </cpu>
    <usb>
      <model>TOSHIBA MK2552GSX ATA Device</model>
    </usb>
    <drive>
      <name>C:</name>
      <volumename>Vista</volumename>
      <size>116,29 GB</size>
      <freespace>25,88 GB</freespace>
    </drive>
    <drive>
      <name>D:</name>
      <volumename>Disk</volumename>
      <size>115,13 GB</size>
      <freespace>114,03 GB</freespace>
    </drive>
    <memory>
      <positioninrow>1</positioninrow>
      <size>2 GB</size>
      <datawidth>64</datawidth>
      <devicelocator>DIMM0</devicelocator>
    </memory>
    <memory>
      <positioninrow>2</positioninrow>
      <size>2 GB</size>
      <datawidth>64</datawidth>
      <devicelocator>DIMM2</devicelocator>
    </memory>
  </hardware>
  <software>
    <printer>
      <drivername>Microsoft XPS Document Writer</drivername>
    </printer>
    <printer>
      <drivername>Microsoft Shared Fax Driver</drivername>
    </printer>
    <user>
      <name>Administrator</name>
    </user>
    <user>
      <name>Guest</name>
    </user>
    <user>
      <name>Hkon</name>
    </user>
    <user>
      <name>HomeGroupUser$</name>
    </user>
    <osinfo>
      <caption>Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate </caption>
      <serialnumber>03426-OEM-8672362-00056</serialnumber>
      <installdate>06/07/2010 15:37:05</installdate>
      <OSArchitecture>64-bit</OSArchitecture>
      <manufacturer>Microsoft Corporation</manufacturer>
    </osinfo>
    <network>
      <IP>158.38.54.48 fe90::8b3:b35e:e5d4:91f7</IP>
      <Name>Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection</Name>
      <MAC>00:1F:3C:8E:32:D9</MAC>
    </network>
  </software>
</computer>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what's in your XML file and what variables you have. Of course it's possible, the question is how to make it in the most efficient way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible possible to compare them, you just can't use compare-object to do it. You'll need to write your own code to compare the property values you're concerned with.  Alternatively, you could export the live data to a temp xml file then re-import it and use compare-object on that.  Then you aren't comparing dissimilar object types.